SQL Server trigger after batch update
I have a table A and I have defined trigger on it as following:
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER tr_A_IUD_FillStuff ON A
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN ... END

Now I am executing a batch in SQL Management Studio:
UPDATE [A] SET [ModifiedDateTime] = @p0
WHERE [UniqueActivityId] = @p1;

UPDATE [A] SET [ModifiedDateTime] = @p2
WHERE [UniqueActivityId] = @p3;

UPDATE [A] SET [ModifiedDateTime] = @p4
WHERE [UniqueActivityId] = @p5;

This execution fires a trigger three times. Is there any way to configure the trigger to be fired one time per a batch?

What is your trigger doing that it makes a difference how many times it's called? It should be agnostic to the number of rows or number of calls.

@Charlieface The trigger is calling a stored procedure, which is heavy in terms of resources, that's why I am interested in the trigger to be fired only once when a batch is completed

OK how about you show what that procedure is doing. I'm going to hazard a guess it can be made more efficient. Better yet, given that it's a procedure being called from the trigger, why don't you just remove it from the trigegr and call it manually?

@Charlieface I am not in charge of the procedure, hence I can't share this code, but "to call procedure manually" is the best workaround for me and the team. The advice of Tom A is helpful, but the SQL-code is produced by Entity Framework, that's why I can't change it in the proposed way

No, triggers fire once per DML statement, not batch. The solution here is to instead change your batch so that it only has one DML statement, rather than many.
You could do that with a CASE expression, such as:
UPDATE A
SET ModifiedDateTime = CASE UniqueActivityId WHEN @P1 THEN @P0
                                             WHEN @P3 THEN @P2
                                             WHEN @P5 THEN @P4
                       END
WHERE UniqueActivityId IN (@P1, @P3, @P5);

This, however, doesn't particularly scale, so you could instead use a table (variable/parameter), which would look more like this:
DECLARE @Parameters table (ID int,
                           ModifiedDateTime datetime) --Data types are guessed:

INSERT INTO @Parameters (ID, ModifiedDateTime)
VALUES(...), --your values would go in here
      (...),...;
UPDATE YT
SET YT.ModifiedDateTime = P.ModifiedDateTime
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN @Parameters P ON A.UniqueActivityId = P.ID

